# AWS S3 - Policy not applying to object owned by another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, policy

I have 3 separate AWS accounts:

- Account 1 - Owns the bucket with the policy stated below
- Account 2 - Places objects in the bucket and sets the ACL for each object to "bucket-owner-full-control"
- Account 3 - Downloads objects from the bucket

The issue I'm having is that when an object is uploaded into the bucket, it is owned by Account 2 which results in Account 3 not being able to download the object.

If I upload the object via Account 1, Account 3 can access it as expected. It appears that the ACL is somehow having an unexpected effect on the permissions.

I have mutiple accounts which act in the same manner as Account 3 and so I want to avoid using ACLs entirely and just control access via the policy.

The bucket policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account3:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-magic-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account3:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-magic-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account2:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-magic-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account2:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-magic-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This can be replicated with the following AWS CLI commands:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket account-1-bucket --key files/asset.txt --body ./asset.txt --profile account-2
aws s3api put-object-acl --acl bucket-owner-full-control --bucket account-1-bucket --key files/asset.txt --profile account-2
aws s3api get-object --bucket account-1-bucket --key files/asset.txt ./asset.tmp --profile account-3
```

I have also tried to set the ACL during the put-object call but that has the same issue.

Comment: It sounds like `bucket-owner-full-control` is not being applied? How have you can firmed that "when an object is uploaded into the bucket, it is owned by Account 2"? Can you show us how your are doing the upload from Account 2, or reproduce the situation using an AWS CLI command that you can provide?

Comment: What if you use `aws s3 cp files/asset.txt s3://account-1-bucket/ --acl bucket-owner-full-control --profile account-2`?